# Set MS Access form property using VBScript

Tags: forms, ms-access, vbscript, properties

I'm trying to edit `.NavigationButtons` property of multiple MS Access `Form` objects using VBScript.

Here's my startup code:

```
Dim access
Set access = CreateObject("Access.Application")

access.OpenCurrentDatabase "d:/mydb.accdb"
```

Now when database is open I can access it's forms by calling `.CurrentProject.AllForms` of `Application` object. This method returns a collection of `AccessObject` objects. I can set their properties by simply calling `.Properties.Add` method, but it sets the property of `AccessObject` and it's not what I want.

I also tried to loop through `.Forms` property of `Application` object. This property stores a collection of forms with real form properties and `.NavigationButtons` is one of them. However, this collection is read-only and I can't set new values to these properties.

Is there any way to update `Form` property from VBScript program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make it work using both `.CurrentProject.AllForms` and `.Forms` methods of `Application` object. I was missing one detail - you have to save form after you changed it's property.

```
For Each form.Name access.CurrentProject.AllForms
    access.DoCmd.OpenForm form.Name, 1
    access.Forms(form.Name).NavigationButtons = True 'Or another property.
    access.DoCmd.Close 2, form.Name, 1 'Where "1" is equal to acSaveYes.
Next
```